# How to crawl publicly available data from linkedin using beatifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, linkedin-api

I was trying to crawl the publicly available topics from linkedin using beautifulsoup. But while trying to scrap I all of a sudden got **Sign up for free to get more** popup and couldnt get any data. Can someone help me with this.

Here is the code i wrote to get the topics:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator
import os
import sys

topics = []

def get_main_topics(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')
    for main_topics in soup.find_all('ul', {'class' : 'quad-column'}):
        for sub_links in main_topics.find_all('a'):
            topic = sub_links.string
            print(topic)
            topics.append(topic)

def get_topics(url, alphabet):
    print('Inside get Topics')
    main_url = str(url) + str(alphabet) + '/'
    if alphabet != 'y' or alphabet != 'z':
        source_code = requests.get(main_url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')
        for main_topics in soup.find_all('ul', {'class' : 'quad-column'})[1]:
            for sub_links in main_topics.find_all('a'):
                sub_url = sub_links.get('href')
                get_main_topics(sub_url)
    else:
        source_code = requests.get(main_url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')
        for main_topics in soup.find_all('ul', {'class' : 'quad-column'}):
            for sub_links in main_topics.find_all('a'):
                topic = sub_links.string
                print(topic)
                topics.append(topic)

def start():
    print('Started Crawling...')
    alphabets = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')
    for alphabet in alphabets:
        get_topics('https://www.linkedin.com/directory/topics-', alphabet)
    fw = open('linkedin_topics.txt', 'w')
    for i in topics:
        try:
            fw.write(i+'\n')
        except:
            print(i)
            continue
    print('Crawling Completed and updated...')
```

on checking the output of beautifulsoup I got this..

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  // Parse the tracking code from cookies.
  var trk = "bf";
  var trkInfo = "bf";
  var cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");
  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
    if ((cookies[i].indexOf("trkCode=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {
      trk = cookies[i].substring(8);
    }
    else if ((cookies[i].indexOf("trkInfo=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {
      trkInfo = cookies[i].substring(8);
    }
  }

  if (window.location.protocol == "http:") {
    // If "sl" cookie is set, redirect to https.
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
      if ((cookies[i].indexOf("sl=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 3)) {
        window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  // Get the new domain. For international domains such as
  // fr.linkedin.com, we convert it to www.linkedin.com
  var domain = "www.linkedin.com";
  if (domain != location.host) {
    var subdomainIndex = location.host.indexOf(".linkedin");
    if (subdomainIndex != -1) {
      domain = "www" + location.host.substring(subdomainIndex);
    }
  }

  window.location.href = "https://" + domain + "/authwall?trk=" + trk + "&trkInfo=" + trkInfo +
      "&originalReferer=" + document.referrer.substr(0, 200) +
      "&sessionRedirect=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
}
</script>
</head></html>
```

Comment: @Shahin thank you for pointing out that. I have changed it, now can you please give me a solution for the question.

Comment: I don't know if it will be possible for you to get the content from linkedin without choosing any browser simulator or their api. As you might be aware that BeautifulSoup can't grab dynamically generated content. However, try to use `selenium` to gatecrash. At first log in with your account and then feed the required url to the parser then i think you will get your data. Hope that helps.